# Increment a float pointer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a `float` pointer `p` from a C++ library which I want to increment in a Python module. When I try to write `p + distance`, I'm receiving the error that the operator `+` would be undefined for `LP_c_float`.

A possible solution is to use `advance(p, distance)` instead, where

```
def advance(pointer, distance, type = ctypes.c_float):
    return ctypes.cast(ctypes.cast(pointer, ctypes.c_voidp).value + distance, ctypes.POINTER(type))
```

However, is the cast to `ctypes.c_voidp` really necessary? Why addition is not defined for `LP_c_float` (or why doesn't it have a similar `value` field)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to increment a pointer, just the value that the pointer points to.  You can use simple indexing to get the next values as shown below.

Assuming you have a `float*` to the first element of an array of data, `p` below is the equivalent:

```
import ctypes as ct

data = (3 * ct.c_float)(1.5, 2.5, 3.5) # (C) float data[3] = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
p = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)(data)  # (C) float* p = data;
print(p, p[0], p[1])
p[0] += 1
p[1] += 2
print(p, p[0], p[1])
p.contents.value += 2  # (C) *p += 1
print(p, p[:len(data)]) # If you know the length, slice data into Python list
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000019FA3E116D0> 1.5 2.5
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000019FA3E116D0> 2.5 4.5
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000019FA3E116D0> [4.5, 4.5, 3.5]
```

To actually increment the pointer itself you have to jump through hoops.  Below increments the pointer by one element, e.g. in C: `p += 1`.

```py
# Get the C address of the first element (Python int)
# and add the size of an element in bytes.
new_address = ct.addressof(p.contents) + ct.sizeof(ct.c_float)
# c_void_p() takes a Python int for initialization.
# Other pointers don't, so a cast is needed.
p = ct.cast(ct.c_void_p(new_address), ct.POINTER(ct.c_float))
print(p, p[:2])
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000019FA3E10F50> [4.5, 3.5]
```

As you can see this is expensive.  Do the pointer math in C instead if you have to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `advance` function in the question actually seemed to do the job, but did I get you right that it instead increments the value the pointer points to?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, `advance` works as is, although keep in mind that `distance` is in bytes.  You might want `distance * ctypes.sizeof(type)` instead so your increment works like C's `p += 1`.  Your `cast(pointer, c_void_p).value` gives the same result as `addressof(p.contents)`.

Comment: You also wrote that this is expensive. I mean, it requires a bit of code, but theoretically all of these (except the increment) could be no-ops. So, is it really expensive in terms of computation time?

Comment: @0xbadf00d they are not no-ops. Each substep is generating a python object. They are not like C casts.